# JSONP request to PHP page not working (cross domain)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, cross-domain, jsonp

This is my PHP page (on a different URL)...

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
?>
stat({"online":1});
```

And this is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var url = 'http://blah.com/jsontest.php?callback=stat';

    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        if (data.online !== undefined) {
            console.log('yay');
        }
    }).error(function() {
        console.log('no');
    });

});
```

For some reason it is always logging 'no' i.e. its running the error function.

Using jQuery 1.5.2 any ideas?

Comment: If you console.log(data) what do you get?

Comment: Is your `getJSON` call recognized as a JSONP one?

Comment: @Nicola — nothing, because the `error` function is being called not the success function.

Comment: @David - i also don't understand the "stat({"online":1});" part in the server side script. It might be obvious, but usually i echo('{"online":1}');die(); on server side to have things work 
P.S. ok, my first comment was really stupiud, sorry! :)

Comment: I believe that if you want to name your own callback function you need to use `$.ajax()` and specify the `jsonpCallback` in the call setup.

Comment: @Nicola — `stat` is part of the text being sent to the client. Anything outside <?php and ?> is template content that is piped direct to STDOUT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, JSON-P is not JSON. The content type should be `application/javascript`. Some browsers may reject JSON-P served as JSON for being unsafe.

Second, getJSON expects that the URL you request to have a `?` for the callback method name (and you'll need to get your PHP to pay attention to `$_GET['callback']`).

Third, if fixing that doesn't work, look at the Net tab in Firebug / Chrome debugger / Dragonfly / etc and see what data is actually going across the wire.

Comment: Can I use JSON for cross domain or do I have to use JSON-P?

Comment: You'll *have* to use JSONP, that's why it was ‘invented’ in the first place.

Comment: +1 for content type
You really should use the built in `callback=?` and read the value on the server. If you use your own hard coded callback, you will most likely run into problems if there are multiple requests open. So the second point here is valid.

Answer (score 0):

There's some shenanigans with having with include a "callback" function.  Apparently you're not returning an object, but a function that was submitted in the original client request.  I only vaguely understand what all that means, however, I do have some code to do this that actually works:

Server Side:

```
<?php
$headers = get_headers($toGetUrl,1);
$return["pop_singer"] = "Britney Spears";
// Right here is where the json object gets wrapped in a function that was submitted under the name "callback"
echo $_GET['callback']."(".json_encode($return).")";
?>
```

Client side ( this is the same thing as $.getJSON() ):

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: serverUrl,
dataType: 'jsonp',
error: function(request, status) {
    // Do some error stuff
},
success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    var property = data.pop_singer;   // equals "Britney Spears"
    // Do some successful stuff
}
```

});